# Is there a log for SQL Server bulk insert error?

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert

I am running a SQL Server `Bulk insert` op and I got this error:

> pypyodbc.DataError: (u'22003', u'[22003] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.')

The file I am trying to upload is very very long so I can not know what row is this error referring to. Is there any error log in SQL Server I could use to find out what is this information about?

Thanks

Comment: Do the docs help? see: https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Troubleshooting-%E2%80%93-Generating-an-ODBC-trace-log

Comment: It shouldn't be hard to find `/\d{10,}/` somewhere in a text file with any regex-capable tool, even VS Code.

Comment: the problem is that this text file is very very very very long one. Nearly 0.1TB. is  u'22003'  a special character?

Comment: Have you tried `fgrep` in a WSL distro?

Comment: No... I don't think I am authorized to install any kind of WSL

Comment: 22003 is the ODBC  error code. This is nothing to do with the failing value